# Disable button if a string is matched from a line in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to build a website using `jquery-1.10.2` where I want to block css related strings like `<style>`, `<link>` etc. I want to disable the submit button if any of those strings match. So far I've managed to block them using `.keyup()` function but if I write more than those tags like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` then it won't work. Here are my codes,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputdivEditor-2').keyup(function () {
        var input = $(this).val();
        if (input == "<style>" || input == "</style>" || input == "<link>") {
            $('#deactivedivEditor-2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }else{
            $('#deactivedivEditor-2').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/su1zk7yz/)

How can I disable the button if any of those strings match from any lines? Need this help badly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `regex` to check if the text contains certain pattern.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var regex = /<\/?style.*?>|<link.*?>/;
    $('#inputdivEditor-2').keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

        $('#deactivedivEditor-2').prop('disabled', regex.test(val));
    });
});
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tusharj/52xd3s11/

**Regex**

1. `/` : Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\/?`: Matches 0 or 1 `/`
3. `.*?`: Matches any character any no. of times
4. `|`: OR in regex

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to match those strings.

```
var regex = /<(style|link)>/;
```

To disable update when the elements are present. That however wouldn't solve all cases. If someone wants he can bypass the regex by writing `<   style  >` or with using different encoding and so on.

In my opinion a better option is to *look at the content from a browser's perspective*. In other words take the input and make an element out of it:

```
var dummyElement = $('<div></div>');
dummyElement.html(input); //contents of the input field
if(dummyElement.find('style').length > 0) {
    //you get the point
}
```

..because there's that one question on SO, which explains why not parse HTML with regexes..
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Just use regex to check anything between `< >` like below:

**[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Guruprasad_Rao/su1zk7yz/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputdivEditor-2').keyup(function () {
        var input = $(this).val();
        var regex=/<*>/;
        if (regex.test(input)) {
            $('#deactivedivEditor-2').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $('#deactivedivEditor-2').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

You can use `.prop('disabled',true)` for disable button and `.prop('disabled',false)` for enable button. Both are used after  `$('#deactivedivEditor-2')`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use regular expressions to check the string with a pattern at any position. The regexp I show below matches on anything between two angular braces - even non html tags too.

Secondly - it is a bit off topic - the best and recommended solution for setting and disabling the "disabled" attribute with jquery is by using the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputdivEditor-2').keyup(function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        var regexp = /]*?>/;
        var isDisabled = regex.test(inputValue);

        $('#deactivedivEditor-2').prop("disabled", isDisabled);
    });
});
```